# (PHP) Help debug tracking script to show only unique items

Tags: php, debugging, tracking

i have this script that i am trying to implement to work on my website and the script is suppose to track what games are being played at the moment but the only problem is that when i call the script to display the entries it would show duplicates and i want the script to actually explore the string and take **only the $gamename and look for duplicates, not the entire string.**

What the script does:
Records the gameID, gamename, gamethumb url, IP and time all separated by |.
Example: 1744|The Simpliest Snowboarding|The Simpliest Snowboarding|77.88.42.26|1264717552

Look for the IP and if already exists update the record with the new info.
If the IP does not exist already write a new line with the information.
If the record is older then 60min erase it.

Its just a simple script that i will use to show what people are currently playing on the website.

```
$dataFile = "visitors2.txt";
$numbergames = 30;
//Please do not edit bellow this line

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$users = array();

//getting
$fp = fopen($dataFile, "r");
flock($fp, LOCK_SH);
while(!feof($fp)) {
$users[] = fgets($fp, 4096);
}
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
$i = 0;
echo '<ul>';
foreach(array_unique($users) as $key => $data) {
list($game2id , $gamename , $gamethumb , , ) = explode("|", $data);
//echo $game2id . $gamename;
if($gamename != "" && $i <= $numbergames) {
$newpageurl = str_replace(" ", "-", strip_tags(trim(str_replace($rplce, "", $gamename))))  ;
$url = $game2id .'-'. $newpageurl .'.html';

echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'"><img src="./arcade/img/'.$gamethumb.'.png" width="35" height="35" border="0" /></a>'.$gamename.'</li>';
}
$i++;

}
```

Please, help and thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're not using a database for this?

Comment: It will be updated hundreds of times a day and database is not a solution :(
My website is already using mysql database heavily.

Answer (score 0):

Your `array_unique()` call is only eliminating duplicate rows - entire rows, not just game names. You need to create an array of just the game names. Then, you can eliminate the dupes.

Something like:

```
$currentGames = array();
$max = 30;
$fp = fopen($dataFile, "r");
flock($fp, LOCK_SH);
while ((count($currentGames) < $max) && (($data = fgetcsv($fg, 0, '|')) !== FALSE) 
{
 if (!in_array($data[1], $currentGames)) $currentGames[$data[0]] = $data[1];
}
```

This will give you an associative array of unique game names with game ids as keys.

Comment: Any ideas how can i put that back together after i eliminated the dupes ? I still need the gamename, gameid and gamethumb :)

Thanks for the help emmychan

Comment: Well, you could create a multi-dimensional array and compare the game id (key) instead of the game name using array_key_exists. i.e. `if (!array_key_exists($data[0], $currentGames)) $currentGames[$data[0]] = array('name' => $data[1], 'thumb' => $data[2]);`